# Issue with displaying all the variable values that is inside while loop on to the TextArea

Tags: java, while-loop

prepareStatement and resultset are already declare at the top of the page.

I want to display off all the values base on my sql to the textarea but only the last value appear. If(res.next()) also does not work - only one value is being displayed.

I am getting only the last value of my while loop so how can I display all of my values... maybe with a loop?

```
btnSearch.addActionListener(( ActionEvent ae) -> {
     if (ae.getSource().equals(btnSearch)) {

    String get_username = friend_username_txtf.getText();

    DB_connection db_connection = new DB_connection(); 

    try{

        String req = "SELECT su.status_update_msg, su.status_timestamp "
            + "FROM status_update_tb as su "
            + "INNER JOIN user_profile as up ON su.user_id = up.user_id "
            + "WHERE up.username=? ";

        preStatement = db_connection.connect().prepareStatement(req);
        preStatement.setString(1, get_username);
        res = preStatement.executeQuery();

        while(res.next()){

        String status_update_time = res.getString("status_timestamp");
        stats_status_txta.setText(status_update_time);

        String friend_status = res.getString("status_update_msg");
        stats_status_txta.setText(friend_status);

                            }

                    } catch(SQLException | NullPointerException ex){

                        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

                    } finally {
                        db_connection.disconnect();
                    }
            }
        });
```

I keep getting only the last value instead of all the values.

Comment: You are using `stats_status_txta.setText` twice.

Comment: you mean to display the 2 values into the same textarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [`JTextComponent.setText(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText(java.lang.String)) documentation: it overwrites any existing value!

Try `stats_status_txta.setText(stats_status_txta.getText() + status_update_time + "\t");` and `stats_status_txta.setText(stats_status_txta.getText() + friend_status + "\n");` instead.

Comment: You mean inside my while loop... will try it and let you know

Answer (score 0):

here is a problem with your initialization logic:

```
while(res.next()){

    String status_update_time = res.getString("status_timestamp");
    stats_status_txta.setText(status_update_time);

    String friend_status = res.getString("status_update_msg");
    stats_status_txta.setText(friend_status);

    }
```

You are setting only the last value of result set string in the textArea, please initialize your textArea in the while loop with different variables something like this:

```
stats_status_txta = new TextArea("");
stats_status_txta.setText(status_update_time);
```

If you want the data in the same text area then you may use new line escape character '\n' after every line, something like this:

```
stats_status_txta.setText(status_update_time+"\n");
```

or `<br/>` will also work in some of the window builders

```
stats_status_txta.setText(status_update_time+"<br/>");
```